# Are there any meaningful differences between Star Wars prequels and their novelizations?

Tags: star-wars, adaptation-comparison, prequels

Are there any meaningful differences between Star Wars prequels and their novelizations?

I mean differences more in the "**contradictions**" meaning, and not those that are of the "this detail was mentioned in the book, but never made it to the movie" tidbits.

Comment: I remember feeling like Jar Jar was *far* less annoying in the novelization of TPM. Comparing the two, Jar Jar is always almost tolerable until the last thing he says or does in a scene. Those last bits weren't in the novelization.

Answer (score 2):

The duel between Palpatine and the Jedi was different. Palpatine beheaded Saesea Tiin by distracting him and also beheaded Kit Fisto.

Comment: Wasn't that what happened in the movie as well, as much as could be seen at high speed?

Comment: Nope, there weren't any beheadings of the other Jedis that accompanied Mace Windu during the attempt to arrest Chancellor Palpatine.

Answer (score 2):

The novelisation of *Revenge of the Sith* does change the duel scene slightly, as Donmax said. It shows Palpatine recording the Jedi's comments or screaming for help just before cutting off the recording, giving the impression that he has prevented a Jedi coup. His comments to Anakin upon making him a Sith Lord are also slightly different. Other than the aforementioned 'parts included in the books but not the films,' that is the only change I can recall. I have not read the *Attack of the Clones* novelisation though.